# asp:ListBox is disabled inside dropdown-menu class

Tags: css, asp.net, listbox

i am showing asp.net Listbox (with multiselect) and dropdown control inside dropdown-menu class. Listbox is not opening or expanding when i click on it while dropdown is working fine. If i place listbox outside dropdown menu class then it's selectable again.

```
 <div class="position-relative float-right">
                                        <i class="ft-filter mb-5" role="button" id="CO0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></i>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" aria-labelledby="CO0" style="border-block-color: navy !important">
                                            <div class="row" style="padding: 15px">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="basicInput">Department</label>
                                                        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstDepartmentForDisposal" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control"></asp:ListBox>
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfDepartmentForDisposal" runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfAllDepartmentForDisposal" runat="server" />
                                                    </fieldset>

                                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="helpInputTop">Item</label>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddItemForDisposal" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" onchange="refAssetsByDisposal();return false;"
                                                            DataValueField="Name" AutoPostBack="False" CssClass="form-control">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" Width="150px" CssClass="btn btn-facebook mr-2" Style="color: white" OnClientClick="refAssetsByDisposal();return false;" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

[image: screenshot of list box and dropdown]

i tried to place listbox outside dropdown class and its working fine there. so its only dropdown class which blocking listbox to expand.